# Verb する in this sentence

Tags: verbs

A building collapsed, but everyone had already evacuated it. Then someone says the following sentence: 全員が避難した後でしたので　幸い　死者はなし

I did not understand the meaning of the verb する after 後で. Could someone explain to me?

お返事ありがとうございます！

Comment: Someone mentioned this in one of your previous questions, but you might have missed it... if you want to thank someone for something before they've done it, you can say よろしくお願いします, not ありがとうございます.

Comment: Yes "saying ありがとう in advance" is one of the most common mistakes learners make :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no する after 後. It's でした, the polite form of だった.

全員が避難した後でしたので
= 全員が避難した後だったので
= because it was after everyone evacuated